# How do I manage to lose 1 point from a question I merely commented on?

Tags: support

[Should I store root vegetables with or without the dirt?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/27761/should-i-store-root-vegetables-with-or-without-the-dirt/67686#67686)

Somehow I got a -1 on this.
Didn't even know that was possible. AFAIK it's all +10 +15, -2
What's the deal?
Not unhappy or anything, I would just like to know what the trigger was so I can put a stop to it.

Answer (score 8):

Please see [the help page on reputation](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation):

Users have to give up one of their own rep points when they downvote a post.

Comment: OK. I do vaguely remember that. Don't remember downvoting anyone recently, but I may have. Thanks, Stephie.

Comment: @WayfaringStranger we cannot check for you, but you can see your own voting history on your user profile - there are tabs for answers, questions, tags, etc., and the last one is votes.